# How can you measure the length of curved grid lines on an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Suppose you have an image like this:

[image: Grid with curved lines]

How can you measure the combined length of all the lines in this image?

I have tried (naively) skeletonising the image and then counting the number of pixels. However, this gives inaccurate results, as diagonal steps are actually longer than vertical/horizontal ones.

My other idea is to generate a chain code for all the line segments , and then use something like Freeman's method to measure the length from the chain code. However, generating the chain code is going to be quite tricky I think, as usually they start/stop at the same point, and this won't work for the grid shape.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Measurement in length in the sense? could you please give an example of the desired output?

Comment: I don't see a grid. where do you see a grid?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: he means a raster grid.

Comment: the more accuracy you want, the more you have to **smooth the curves** you extract from walking the pixels (but that'll also eventually cause its own errors). the base case is, each pixel causes a point on the curve. that'll give you right angles. next optimization is "going diagonal", but that'll still cost you 1+1.41 if you move like a knight, which _should_ only cost 2.236, which gives an overestimation factor of at most 1.08 (1+sqrt(2))/hypot(1,2)

Comment: Mahesh- I mean that if each pixel, for example is 1 mm wide, then what is the combined length of the lines seen in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the strokes are 3 pixels wide. So dividing the number of black pixels by three isn't a too bad approximation.

Alternatively, use a *thinning* algorithm to reduce the width to a single pixel (connexity 8), then *seed-fill* the whole outline. You will use a simple recursive 8-ways fill, and count the lateral and diagonal moves separately. In the end the length is given by L + D√2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Can I ask a few questions. I understand why I should use a thinning algorithm. In fact, I have ready done this (result not shown above), using the 'skeletonise' algorithm in a image proc pkg  (imagej). It works quite well but I then got into trouble trying to extract length from that image. I'm a bit confused on the purpose of your seedfill....is this just to fill in any gaps on the skeletonised lines?

Comment: I think the seed-"fill" was meant to be a _line following/extraction_ (resulting in a graph of pixels and edges) rather than filling any "areas"

Comment: @Hooke: as said by Christophe the filling will in fact be edge following as the "region" is one pixel wide, 8-connected. And I repeat that a simple recursive 8-ways seed fill, modified to count the directions taken. (There are no gaps.)